# I am having a problem with Query selectors for this project website

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am learning web dev, and I am a beginner. I have learned a tiny bit about DOM manipulation and I am facing a small issue with a click event.

[The HTML CSS and JS code in codepen](https://codepen.io/meroosa/pen/dymbEGm)

Please click on the pizza image. When you click on it, the box shadow should remain even after you do not hover over the pizza and the gray link bar bellow is now yellow even when you don't hover over it. Click back on it and it returns to normal, neat!

Please now click on the pavlova (the sweet pinkish dessert). It doesn't work even though it shares the exact same css classes and everything when it comes to style.

I hope I have described my problem properly. If anything is not clear I will explain more. I have been on this for a while and I really don't know how to fix it. I will include the code here as well but everything is on code pen above, whichever is preferred.

```js
const theFoodImg = document.querySelector('.food-img');
const recipeLink = document.querySelector('.recipe-link');
const linkIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-link');
const pinTopBar = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack');
const topBar = document.querySelector('#top-bar');
const pinColor = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack');


theFoodImg.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (theFoodImg.classList.contains('active')) {
    theFoodImg.classList.remove('active');
    theFoodImg.classList.remove('food-hover');
    theFoodImg.classList.add('food-img');
    recipeLink.classList.add('recipe-link');
    recipeLink.classList.remove('click');
    linkIcon.classList.add('white-link')
    linkIcon.classList.remove('blue-link')
  } else {
    theFoodImg.classList.remove('food-img');
    theFoodImg.classList.add('active');
    recipeLink.classList.remove('recipe-link');
    recipeLink.classList.add('click');
    linkIcon.classList.remove('white-link')
    linkIcon.classList.add('blue-link')

  }
})

theFoodImg.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  if (theFoodImg.classList.contains('active') !== true) {
    theFoodImg.classList.add('food-hover');
  }
})


if (topBar.classList.contains('fix')) {
  pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
}
pinTopBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (topBar.classList.contains('fix') !== true) {
    topBar.classList.add('fix');
    pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
  } else {
    topBar.classList.remove('fix');
    pinColor.style.color = 'black';
  }
})
```

```css
/* css reset */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gold;
}


/* banner and title styles */

div#banner {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/MgBrNdY/background-img.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9000em rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
  /* change later for media queries */
}


/* title style */

h1#large-screen-title {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
}

div#top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 234);
  height: min-content;
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  height: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px goldenrod;
}

img#odin-logo {
  height: 5em;
}

i.fa-thumbtack {
  float: right;
  padding: 1em;
}

i.fa-thumbtack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  div#banner {
    height: 80vh;
  }
  h1#title-index {
    height: 60vh;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid white;
  }
  div#top-bar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/* recipe card styles */

div#recipe-card-container {
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}


/*each recipe card */

div#recipe-card-container>div.each-recipe {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#recipe-card-container div.recipe-img {
  /* background-color: red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 450ms;
}


/*recipe link within each card */

div.recipe-link {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 450ms;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

div.recipe-link:hover {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  transition: 450ms;
}


/* when clicked add this style */

.click {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: 450ms;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/**/

i.fa-link {
  float: left;
}

div.recipe-link:hover>i.fa-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}


/*when clicked, target i.fa-link color */

.white-link {
  color: white;
}

.blue-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}


/* food image style on card */

.food-img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.food-img {
  width: 100%;
}

img.food-hover:hover,
.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(189, 80, 12);
  height: 105%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*grey bar with copyright*/

div.copy {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  div#recipe-card-container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 500px rgb(85, 63, 63);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Odin Recipes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="top-bar" class="fix">
      <a href="https://www.theodinproject.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7nhgfNJ/odin-logo.png" alt="" id="odin-logo" /></a>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbtack"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <hr />
  <h1 id="large-screen-title">Odin Recipes</h1>
  <br /><br />
  <hr />


  <div id="recipe-card-container">


    <div class="each-recipe">
      <div class="recipe-img">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mDCCZTW/pizza.jpg" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
      </div>
      <a href="/recipes/pizza.html">
        <div class="recipe-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pizza Recipe
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="each-recipe">
      <div class="recipe-img">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5cQCFWP/pavlova.png" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
      </div>
      <a href="/recipes/pavlova.html">
        <div class="recipe-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova Recipe
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="each-recipe">
      <div class="recipe-img">
        <img src="/recipes/images/" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
      </div>
      <a href="/recipes/">
        <div class="recipe-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova Recipe
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2022</div>





  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb94170dc7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `const theFoodImg = document.querySelector('.food-img');` just selects the first element matching the selector, which is the pizza. Use `const theFoodImg = document.querySelectorAll('.food-img');` to select all of them. Then you need to write a loop to iterate over all the images. And the listener function will need to operate on the current image and related elements using DOM navigation methods.

Comment: There's no need for the codepen when the stack snippet works.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot for your reply. Alright I think I understand, I need get an array of all of the elements with the desired selector. 

I don't understand this part: >And the listener function will need to operate on the current image and related elements using DOM navigation methods.

what do you mean? using querySelectorAll and a for loop is not enough?

Comment: For instance, `recipeLink.classList.add('recipe-link');` needs to change so it only updates the `recipeLink` in the same div as the current `foodImg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below snippet. i have updated theFoodImg variable to theFoodImgs and leveraged querySelectorAll to get a node list of all the .food-img class elements.
Then use a foreach loop on the nodelist to loop it and add your listeners.
You may want to update more of your variables from querySelector to querySelectorAll. I have done this one to get you headed down the correct path.

**Edit added a recipeLink class. cant key off of a class in the selector that is being added and removed. The snippet should be in full working order now.

```js
const theFoodImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.food-img'),
  pinTopBar = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack'),
  topBar = document.querySelector('#top-bar'),
  pinColor = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack');
let recipeLink, linkIcon;
theFoodImgs.forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    recipeLink = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.recipeLink');
    linkIcon = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.fa-link');
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){
        this.classList.remove('active');
        this.classList.remove('food-hover');
        this.classList.add('food-img');
        recipeLink.classList.add('recipe-link');
        recipeLink.classList.remove('click');
        linkIcon.classList.add('white-link')
        linkIcon.classList.remove('blue-link')
    } else {
        this.classList.remove('food-img');
        this.classList.add('active');
        recipeLink.classList.remove('recipe-link');
        recipeLink.classList.add('click');
        linkIcon.classList.remove('white-link')
        linkIcon.classList.add('blue-link')

    }
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
      if (el.classList.contains('active') !== true) {
          el.classList.add('food-hover');
      }
  })
});


if(topBar.classList.contains('fix')) {
    pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
}
pinTopBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(topBar.classList.contains('fix') !== true) {
        topBar.classList.add('fix');
        pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
  }
  else  {
    topBar.classList.remove('fix');
    pinColor.style.color = 'black';
    }
})
```

```css
/* css reset */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gold;
}
/* banner and title styles */
div#banner {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/MgBrNdY/background-img.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9000em rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh; /* change later for media queries */
}

/* title style */

h1#large-screen-title {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
}

div#top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 234);
  height: min-content;
}
.fix {
  position: fixed;
  height: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px goldenrod;
}
img#odin-logo {
  height: 5em;
}
i.fa-thumbtack {
  float: right;
  padding: 1em;
}
i.fa-thumbtack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  div#banner {
    height: 80vh;
  }
  h1#title-index {
    height: 60vh;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid white;
  }
  div#top-bar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

/* recipe card styles */

div#recipe-card-container {
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

/*each recipe card */
div#recipe-card-container > div.each-recipe {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#recipe-card-container div.recipe-img {
  /* background-color: red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 450ms;
}

/*recipe link within each card */
div.recipe-link {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 450ms;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
div.recipe-link:hover {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  transition: 450ms;
}

/* when clicked add this style */
.click {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: 450ms;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/**/

i.fa-link {
  float: left;
}
div.recipe-link:hover > i.fa-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
/*when clicked, target i.fa-link color */
.white-link {
  color: white;
}
.blue-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}


/* food image style on card */
.food-img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img.food-img {
  width: 100%;
} 
img.food-hover:hover,
.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(189, 80, 12);
  height: 105%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*grey bar with copyright*/
div.copy {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  div#recipe-card-container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 500px rgb(85, 63, 63);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Odin Recipes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      <div id="top-bar" class="fix">
        <a href="https://www.theodinproject.com/"
          ><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7nhgfNJ/odin-logo.png" alt="" id="odin-logo"
        /></a>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbtack"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <h1 id="large-screen-title">Odin Recipes</h1>
    <br /><br />
    <hr />


    <div id="recipe-card-container">
      
      
      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/mDCCZTW/pizza.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="food-img food-hover"
          />
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/pizza.html">
          <div class="recipe-link recipeLink">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pizza
            Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      

      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5cQCFWP/pavlova.png" alt="" class="food-img food-hover"/>
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/pavlova.html">
          <div class="recipe-link recipeLink">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img
            src="/recipes/images/"
            alt=""
            class="food-img food-hover"
          />
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/">
          <div class="recipe-link recipeLink">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova
            Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      </div>

      <div class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2022</div>
  




    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb94170dc7.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click on Pavlova, "Click here for pizza recipe" changes color, not "Click here for pavlova recipe".

Comment: Yup, i did not update all of the variables. i gave the op a working path to understanding querySelector vs querySelectorAll. As noted in the answer i only updated 1 variable.

Comment: But getting this right is a relatively advanced topic. The roadmap doesn't really tell you how to get the right `recipeLink` from `el`.

Comment: Cool, i will update the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the process to not query ANY loops. Instead I'm assigning the event handler to the parent of the recipes. Then I look for the active element and REMOVE the active class from the recipe itself. Instead of adding/removing classes from each element, I simply add an active class to the recipe parent and use CSS to modify the children of the active class.

```js
const recipes = document.querySelector("#recipe-card-container")

recipes.addEventListener("click", function(el) {
  let target = el.target;
  if (target.className.indexOf("food-img") > -1) {
    let active = document.querySelector(".each-recipe.active");
    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    }
    target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
/* css reset */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gold;
}


/* banner and title styles */

div#banner {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/MgBrNdY/background-img.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9000em rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
  /* change later for media queries */
}


/* title style */

h1#large-screen-title {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
}

div#top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 234);
  height: min-content;
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  height: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px goldenrod;
}

img#odin-logo {
  height: 5em;
}

i.fa-thumbtack {
  float: right;
  padding: 1em;
}

i.fa-thumbtack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  div#banner {
    height: 80vh;
  }
  h1#title-index {
    height: 60vh;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid white;
  }
  div#top-bar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/* recipe card styles */

div#recipe-card-container {
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}


/*each recipe card */

div#recipe-card-container>div.each-recipe {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#recipe-card-container div.recipe-img {
  /* background-color: red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 450ms;
}


/*recipe link within each card */

div.recipe-link {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 450ms;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

div.recipe-link:hover {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  transition: 450ms;
}


/* when clicked add this style */

.active .recipe-link {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: 450ms;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/**/

i.fa-link {
  float: left;
}

div.recipe-link:hover>i.fa-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}


/*when clicked, target i.fa-link color */

.recipe-link i {
  color: white;
}

.each-recipe.active i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}


/* food image style on card */

.food-img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.food-img {
  width: 100%;
}

img.food-hover:hover,
.each-recipe.active img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(189, 80, 12);
  height: 105%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*grey bar with copyright*/

div.copy {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  div#recipe-card-container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 500px rgb(85, 63, 63);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="recipe-card-container">


  <div class="each-recipe">
    <div class="recipe-img">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mDCCZTW/pizza.jpg" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
    </div>
    <a href="/recipes/pizza.html">
      <div class="recipe-link">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Click here for Pizza Recipe
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="each-recipe">
    <div class="recipe-img">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5cQCFWP/pavlova.png" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
    </div>
    <a href="/recipes/pavlova.html">
      <div class="recipe-link">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova Recipe
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="each-recipe">
    <div class="recipe-img">
      <img src="/recipes/images/" alt="" class="food-img food-hover" />
    </div>
    <a href="/recipes/">
      <div class="recipe-link">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova Recipe
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2022</div>





<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb94170dc7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked!

```js
// const theFoodImg = document.querySelector('.food-img');
// const recipeLink = document.querySelector('.recipe-link');
// const linkIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-link');
const pinTopBar = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack');
const topBar = document.querySelector('#top-bar');
const pinColor = document.querySelector('.fa-thumbtack');


// theFoodImg.addEventListener('click', function() {
//     if(theFoodImg.classList.contains('active')){
//             theFoodImg.classList.remove('active');
//             theFoodImg.classList.remove('food-hover');
//             theFoodImg.classList.add('food-img');
//             recipeLink.classList.add('recipe-link');
//         recipeLink.classList.remove('click');
//         linkIcon.classList.add('white-link')
//         linkIcon.classList.remove('blue-link')
//     } else {
//         theFoodImg.classList.remove('food-img');
//         theFoodImg.classList.add('active');
//         recipeLink.classList.remove('recipe-link');
//         recipeLink.classList.add('click');
//         linkIcon.classList.remove('white-link');
//         linkIcon.classList.add('blue-link');

//     }
// })

// theFoodImg.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
//     if (theFoodImg.classList.contains('active') !== true) {
//         theFoodImg.classList.add('food-hover');
//     }
// })


if(topBar.classList.contains('fix')) {
    pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
}
pinTopBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(topBar.classList.contains('fix') !== true) {
        topBar.classList.add('fix');
        pinColor.style.color = 'goldenrod';
  }
  else  {
    topBar.classList.remove('fix');
    pinColor.style.color = 'black';
    }
})


const recipeContainer = document.querySelector('div#recipe-card-container');
const linkIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-link');


recipeContainer.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    if(event.target.classList.contains('food-img') || event.target.classList.contains('food-hover')){
        if(event.target.classList.contains('active')==false) {
            event.target.classList.remove('food-img');
            event.target.classList.add('active');
            const recipeImg = event.target.parentElement;
            const aTag = recipeImg.nextElementSibling;
            const recipeLink = aTag.firstElementChild;
            const linkIcon = recipeLink.firstElementChild;
            recipeLink.classList.remove('recipe-link');
            recipeLink.classList.add('click');
            linkIcon.classList.remove('white-link');
            linkIcon.classList.add('blue-link');



            if(!event.target.classList.contains('food-hover')){
                event.target.classList.add('food-hover'); 
            }
        } else {
            event.target.classList.remove('active');
            event.target.classList.remove('food-hover');
            event.target.classList.add('food-img');
            const recipeImg = event.target.parentElement;
            const aTag = recipeImg.nextElementSibling;
            const recipeLink = aTag.firstElementChild;
            const linkIcon = recipeLink.firstElementChild;
            linkIcon.classList.add('white-link');
            linkIcon.classList.remove('blue-link');
            recipeLink.classList.add('recipe-link');
            recipeLink.classList.remove('click');
            }

    } 
})
```

```css
/* css reset */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gold;
}
/* banner and title styles */
div#banner {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/MgBrNdY/background-img.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9000em rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh; /* change later for media queries */
}

/* title style */

h1#large-screen-title {
  color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 4em;
}

div#top-bar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 234);
  height: min-content;
}
.fix {
  position: fixed;
  height: 15%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px goldenrod;
}
img#odin-logo {
  height: 5em;
}
i.fa-thumbtack {
  float: right;
  padding: 1em;
}
i.fa-thumbtack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  div#banner {
    height: 80vh;
  }
  h1#title-index {
    height: 60vh;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid white;
  }
  div#top-bar {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

/* recipe card styles */

div#recipe-card-container {
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

/*each recipe card */
div#recipe-card-container > div.each-recipe {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#recipe-card-container div.recipe-img {
  /* background-color: red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 45vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 450ms;
}

/*recipe link within each card */
div.recipe-link {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 450ms;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.recipe-link:hover {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  transition: 450ms;
}

/* when clicked add this style */
.click {
  background-color: #eece1a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: 450ms;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/**/

i.fa-link {
  float: left;
}
div.recipe-link:hover > i.fa-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
/*when clicked, target i.fa-link color */
.white-link {
  color: white;
}
.blue-link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

/* food image style on card */
.food-img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img.food-img {
  width: 100%;
}
img.food-hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
}
img.food-img:hover,
.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(189, 80, 12);
  height: 105%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
  transition: 450ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*grey bar with copyright*/
div.copy {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  margin-top: 30vh;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
  div#recipe-card-container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 700px rgb(85, 63, 63);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  div#recipe-card-container div.recipe-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    border-radius: 3px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .food-img {
    height: 30vh;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  img.food-hover:hover,
  .active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(189, 80, 12);
    height: 32vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(189, 80, 12, 0.637);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Odin Recipes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      <div id="top-bar" class="fix">
        <a href="https://www.theodinproject.com/"
          ><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7nhgfNJ/odin-logo.png" alt="" id="odin-logo"
        /></a>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbtack"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <h1 id="large-screen-title">Odin Recipes</h1>
    <br /><br />
    <hr />

    <div id="recipe-card-container">
      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mDCCZTW/pizza.jpg" alt="" class="food-img" />
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/pizza.html">
          <div class="recipe-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pizza
            Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5cQCFWP/pavlova.png" alt="" class="food-img" />
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/pavlova.html">
          <div class="recipe-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova
            Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="each-recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img">
          <img src="/recipes/images/" alt="" class="food-img" />
        </div>
        <a href="/recipes/">
          <div class="recipe-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-link white-link"></i>Click here for Pavlova
            Recipe
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2022</div>

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb94170dc7.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```